# Matrix comparison depend on one scalar variable

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, positive-definite, linear-control

Let $A$, $B$, $K$ be $n\times n$, $n\times m$ and $m\times n$ matrix respectively. $\alpha_i>0$ is a scalar. Consider the following matrix:

$H_i=\int_0^\infty e^{(A+\alpha_i BK)^Tt}(\alpha_iI+\alpha_i^2K^TK)e^{(A+\alpha_i BK)t}dt$, where $A+\alpha_i BK$ is stable.

If $\alpha_i>\alpha_j$, is $H_i\geq H_j$? Namely, $H_i-H_j$ is positive semi-definite.

By numerical examples, it seems to be true, but is there a proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an idea, not a real hint: If you write $P_i(t) = e^{(A+\alpha_i BK)}, Q_i = \alpha_i(I + K^TK)$, then $H_i - H_j = \int_0^\infty (P_i(t)^TQ_iP_i(t) - P_j(t)^TQ_jP_j(t))dt$. Can you add some zeros in the integrand, like $P_i(t)^TQ_j P_j(t) - P_i(t)^TQ_j P_j(t)$ to trace it back to the sum of some matrices which are (hopefully) p.s.d?

Comment: I have used lyapunov equation to analyze the problem, because the matrix $H_i$ is exactly the explicit solution to the lyapunov equation. Therefore we can get rid of the integral and analyze the lyapunov equation instead. That's what I got so far.